# What are risks to users if pages do not have reCAPTCHA?

Tags: web, captcha

I understand how reCAPTCHA mitigates risk for site owners but **how does reCAPTCHA benefit users**?

With hackers exploiting fake reCAPTCHA to trick users into clicking and/or entering secure information **does it increase risks for users**?

Comment: Please keep to one question per post.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think reCAPTCHA provides any security for the user but is used to help protect the website itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reCAPTCHA is a specific kind of [captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA), and I don't think the benefits are different from those of any other type.

A captcha has no *direct* benefit to users. It's all about protecting the site from bots.

A captcha may have *indirect* benefits to users. For example, a bot might try to log into a site with observed or guessable user names, and weak passwords. Captchas are one of several complementary ways to limit the rate of such attempts, and therefore they help in protecting some accounts.

Comment: agree on the direct benefits and like that you considered possible indirect benefits